# How to remove one added Permission from React-native project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-permissions

In my React-native project, once I added one write external storage permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`  file like below-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And using this permission, I made some build. But later I realized that this permission is not required in my project. So, I wanted to remove this permission. So, I just removed the Permission line in my Manifest file and made one android build.

**But the problem is----**

in app info, it is still showing that it is taking Storage permission.

So, I need one solution to remove this permission completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.packagename">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: It is showing following error-

The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.

Comment: @S.M.Asif use this also `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in start of `manifest tag`